# How to force Mono MVC3 application to show TempData in current response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mono

If ASP.NET MVC2 code below shows message "Test" in Create controller response.

In Mono message does not appear apper in Create view.

Message appears in next response invoked after create.

How to dorce Mono to show TempData value in same request like in ASP.NET ?

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult Create()
{
 TempData["Message"] = "Test";
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


public ActionResult Index() {
  return View();
  }
```

Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <% if (TempData["Message"]!=null) {
        %>
    $(function() {
        setTimeout( function() {
           showMessage ( '<%= TempData["Message"] as string %>');
           }, 300 );
      });
        <% } %>
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you consuming the `TempData` value inside the controller action and not inside the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    TempData["Message"] = "Test";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Index() 
{
    ViewData["Message"] = TempData["Message"];
    return View();
}
```

and inside the view:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <% if (ViewData["Message"] != null) { %>
        $(function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                showMessage (<%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["Message"]) %>);
            }, 300);
        });
    <% } %>
    </script>
</head>
```

By the way instead of using `ViewData`, I would recommend you using a view model and have your view strongly typed to this view model.

Comment: showMessage is part of Site.Master. This is generic message showing method used by all pages. How to create strongly typed view to Site.Master ?